# jquery content accordion menu, issue with content bouncing open when trying to close

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have made a form and if you click on the Info image it drops down with more information, however if i click on the image to close. It with close but then bounce back open.

If I click just next to the image it will close properly.

Any ideas why this happens?

link:
http://www.vestedutility.com.au/home_safety_check.php

Comment: You should post a fiddle and some of your code where you handle the click events. I'm guessing you might have multiple events firing, thus making it first close then reopen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the line from your code:

```
if(jQuery(e.target).is('.active')) {
```

To

```
if(jQuery(this).is('.active')) {
```